# AngularJS - Passing ID from a page and populate in other page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, breeze

I am new to AngularJS. In my project I have a search screen when search I will get the search result in the ngGrid.
On click of any row in the grid, it should populate the details of that row in other page. Basically, I need to pass the ID of the selected record to the other page. I don't know how to handle this in AngularJS (I am using AngularJS HotTowel template) and Breeze for data access logic.

Appreciate if you could provide me link or any where it is implemented which I could refer.

Comment: [Routing Tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07)

Answer (score 0):

You can create service and share values for instance

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.factory('ShareData', function() {
var shared;
    return {
     setValue: function(val){
          shared = val;
     },
     getValue: function(){
         return shared;
    }
});

function FirstCtrl($scope, ShareData){
  ShareData.setValue(1);
}

function SecondCtrl($scope, ShareData){
  $scope.data =   ShareData.getValue();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need $routeParams for this.

Below is an example of the routing configuration:

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["ngRoute"])
.config(["$routeProvider", function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            controller: "HomeController",
            templateUrl: "/home/main",
        })
        .when("/products/:category", {
            controller: "ProductController",
            templateUrl: "/product/index"
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: "/"
        });
}]);
```

**Product Controller**

```
angular.module("app")
.controller("ProductController",["$scope","$routeParams", function($scope,$routeParams){
   $scope.category = $routeParams.category;
   alert($scope.category);
}]);
```

**'Main' View**

```
<a ng-href="#/products/ladies">Ladies</a>
```

check this URL for more info:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams